# Constructors in Programming languages

Tags: c#, java, .net, constructor

Why `constructor` is not considered as `member` of a class ?
Is there any specific reason ?

Thanks and regards.

Comment: Hey that wasn't a homework !
That was one of the basic Q's that any java programmer would come across with.

Comment: Haha, I was just about to add a homework tag ;)

Comment: Homework tags should only be added by the OP - others have no means of knowing if  a question is homework or not.

Comment: Not homework? Why is this guy asking the exact question with the exact wording on the exact same day?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2796790/programming-languages-and-constructors

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I reject the premise of the question. A constructor *is* a member of a class or struct in C#.

I refer you to section 3.4.4 ("Class members") of the C# specification, which enumerates the members of a class:

> A class declaration may contain
>   declarations of constants, fields,
>   methods, properties, events, indexers,
>   operators, instance constructors,
>   destructors, static constructors and
>   types.

Clearly constructors are members of a class. Why do you believe that a constructor is not a member? Who told you that lie?

Comment: I agree, as there are cases in C# where the constructor is not even called (such as during DataContract serialization.)  The constructor is given special treatment by the language and runtime, but it's still essentially a method.  In particular, a constructor on a struct is called with an IL `call` OpCode.  I've never tried doing that with IL on a reference type, though; I'm guessing the CLR would complain.

Comment: Just tried to Call the ctor on a constructed reference type and received a VerificationException "Operation could destabilize the runtime", so a ctor is a member, but definitely given special treatment.

Answer (score 8):

Members are inherited to subclasses. Constructors must not be inherited, so they are not considered to be members.

Constructors are not inherited, because their task is to initialize attributes of *their specific class*. Any subclass must initialize its additional attributes, and for this task it needs an own constructor that knows about the additional attributes.

Also, each constructor **must** call one of its superclass constructors directly or indirectly as its first action, to give the superclass a change for initialization.

Comment: Just to clarify, this answer applies to the Java side of the question. In C#, constructors are class members.

Answer (score 7):

In C++, constructors certainly are considered to be members of a class - the C++ Standard describes them in a section headed "Special Member Functions".

Answer (score 2):

As i see it,constructor is not a method but a life-cycle hook provided by Java (another life-cycle hook is finalize).
This gives you a chance to do things which would be pre-requisite before any method could be called on the object.So there is clear distinction between methods and constructor, hence even the Language specs has it but the intent is not totally clear from the specs.

Answer (score 1):

"Understanding constructors" :
http://www.javaworld.com/jw-10-2000/jw-1013-constructors.html

Answer (score 0):

As Eric points [out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793611/constructors-in-programming-languages/2794599#2794599), in C# constructors *are* considered class members. In fact, it is simply a class method with additional metadata used by the compiler and runtime so the constructor method is invoked during object creation.

Although it doesn't say why, according to the [Java Language Specification, Second Edition](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/classes.doc.html#21831) constructors, static initializers, and instance initializers are not members.

Comment: It's the job of a specification to specify things, not really to discuss why (which I believe you'll so more so in the next edition). Anyway I think the linked sentence about not being inherited says enough.